# Difference between `f=lambda t,y: -y` and `f=lambda y:-y`

Tags: python

I would like to know whether there is a difference between defining the same function as given bellow:

`f=lambda t,y: -y`  and `f=lambda y:-y`

I'm learning how to solve ODEs in python and they are using this simple function in examples.
I get that `y` depends on `t` for the differential equation to make sense.
So when we define a function using lambda with `t` and `y` in the left hand side but the right hand side actually contains only `y`, does it says y depends on t?

Comment: yes, those are two different things, with two parameters, it is required to pass those two parameters to the function, however, your function doesn't actually use the parameter, so the result doesn't depend on it.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `f=lambda t, y: -y` takes two arguments but the `t` is unused, and `f=lambda y: -y` only takes one. To put it in mathematical terms:

- `f=lambda t, y: -y`  = `f(t, y) = -y`
- `f=lambda y: -y`  = `f(y) = -y`